# Adding a large brace before a body of text

Tags: math-mode, cases

[image]

How to write the above using Latex ?

Comment: You are searching for the `cases` environment from »[amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)«.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You might also be interested in: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115360/putting-a-header-above-the-cases-in-an-equation [It deals with the same mathematical equation (-; ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cases` environment from `amsmath` package.

The code that illustrates how to do it is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \[
    P_v(E/k,T) =
                 \begin{cases}
                    1       & \text{if $T\geq 0$} \\
                    0       & \text{if $T = 0$} \\
                    -1      & \text{if $T\rightarrow\infty$}
                 \end{cases}
 \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\text{if $T\geq 0$}` is even better. The infinity symbol's name is `\infty`.

Comment: @egreg: Thank you very much for your comment! I have just edited my answer!

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\[P_v(E/k,T)=
\begin{cases}
1-a_vT+N_{k/Q}(v)T^2, & \mbox{good reduction} \\
1-T, & \mbox{split multicative reduction}\\
1+T, & \mbox{non split multicative reduction}\\
1, & \mbox{aditive reduction}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Out put will look like
[image]

Comment: With `mathtools` package you have the `cases*` environment which sets the second column in text mode, so you don't have to write —in this case— `\mbox{…}`.

Comment: @Manuel `cases*` is available only with `mathtools`. Instead of `\mbox` I'd use `\text`.

Comment: @egreg Isn't that what I said? :) And I also use `\text`, but I don't know in what cases I should use `\mbox`?

Comment: `\text` will also give same output as `\mbox`, and I don't know the real difference between this two command.

Comment: `\text` adapts to the surrounding text style. If you are in a theorem with the font set in sans serif, italics and small caps (if that exists :D), then if you use `\text` you will get that same style.